# LTSpice simulation problem with calculus of power

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to determine the optimal resistance of a simple circuit which would maximise the power harvested.

[image]

The calculus of V(Y) is funtionning

[image]

But the one of PRMS and PAVG is not

[image]

I changed my circuit (deleted Y which was indeed useless) but i still does not work. What can I do ?

[image]

Comment: IDK the syntax errors. But the optimum load will match the impedance of C @ f given

Comment: Yes, the syntax of your .meas statements is incorrect. Read the documentation.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson where ?

Comment: https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html

Answer (score 2):

You labeled the ground node as `X`, but the ground is global, it can only have one value: `0` (zero). When you referenced `V(X,Y)`, LTspice cannot find any node `Y` and so your measurement fails.

Solution: don't assign the same net two, different labels. In the case of `GND`, it will always remain `GND`, no matter what, while otherwise the usual action is to consider the last applied label. However, you shouldn't count on this and take care that you just don't assign two different labels to the same node.

Minor question: does your OS not support a print screen function of some sort? The moiree can make it difficult to read.

---

Maybe a picture will say a thousand words?

[image: 1001]

Comment: It does, i will think about it next time sry

Comment: @Julien Not lastly, stepping between more than one order of magnitude my be better done with `.step oct` or `.step dec`.

Comment: Where can i put this command.

Comment: Besides i still cannot understand why LTspice doesn’t understand V(X,Y). The tension of X is 0 and Y is non-zero

Comment: @Julien, because, as the answer says, there is no node `X`. You've attached a label to the `GND` node, but SPICE treats the `GND` node specially and doesn't let you rename it.

Comment: @Julien Maybe there is a language barrier, in which case a picture should say more. See the edit (but also re-read the answer, don't skip).

Comment: @Julien, if you want to create a node named `X` that is always at exactly the same potential as the ground node, you can connect a 0-V voltage source between `GND` and `X`.

Comment: ...or use `[Misc]/jumper`, or its equivalent, a zero valued resistor (needs to be numeric literal `0`, not evaluated).

Comment: I was hoping your post was going to be a camera photo of your answer preview render.

Comment: @SteKulov I could not have done that! What if the moiree pattern didn't match?